# Why doesn't ADL work with functions defined outside of a namespace?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I know that my compiler in the example below will execute the function `First::fun()`, because of Argument-Dependent name Lookup (ADL)/Koenig lookup and in order to execute `Second::fun()` this needs to be explicitly called in the `main` function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace First
{
    enum Enum
    {
        FIRST
    };

    void fun(First::Enum symbol)
    {
        cout << "First fun\n";
    }
}

namespace Second
{
    void fun(First::Enum symbol)
    {
        cout << "Second fun\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    fun(First::FIRST);  // Calls First::fun()
}
```

However, when adding another function `fun()` outside of the namespaces (see code below) and calling `fun()` without a prefixed namespace the compiler gives an ambiguity error. The functions inside the namespaces can still be called by explicitly prefixing the namespace, but `fun()` is unreachable. Why doesn't the compiler prefer the function outside of the namespaces when none are explicitly called? Is there a specific reason this behaviour is avoided?

```
// ^ Namespaces are still here

fun(First::Enum symbol)
{
    cout << "No namespace fun\n";
}    

int main()
{
    fun(First::FIRST);  // Doesn't compile: ambiguity!
}
```

**EDIT**

As [Yksisarvinen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976805/yksisarvinen) rightfully pointed out, the global `fun()` can still be called by prefixing with the global namespace: `::fun(First::FIRST);`.

However, this still leaves me with the question: Why doesn't the compiler prefer the global `fun()` in the ambiguous call?

Comment: Note: global `fun` is reachable just the same as the namespaced ones, you need to prefix it with global namescape: `::fun(First::FIRST)`

Comment: Oh thanks! That actually answers the question already. I was not aware of this!

Comment: As an added meta question, how do I mark my question as solved now? I can't mark a comment as solution afaik

Comment: I guess I could answer, but I don't really know why this call is ambiguous. I thought ADL should choose `::First::fun()` even with the global function present, but obviously that's not correct.

Comment: In that case I'll leave my question up in the hope that someone can answer that part, because I am interested in that as well.

Comment: *"Why doesn't the compiler prefer the global fun() in the ambiguous call?"* That's just how the language works. Why should it prefer one over the other?

Comment: "That's just how the language works" is not a constructive answer in a question about how the language works.

Comment: @HylkevanderVeen Sorry if that sounded offensive, it wasn't intended. Since you seem to have already figured out that funcitons found by regular (unqualified) lookup have the same priority as the ones found by ADL (the answer below just restates it in proper terms), I assumed that you wanted to know why the language is designed this way. Only the people who designed the language know why they did this, we can only speculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why doesn't the compiler prefer the global `fun()` in the ambiguous call?

The global `fun` is found by [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), and `First::fun` is found by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), both are put in overload set and overload resolution can't select one.

> These function names are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments in addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup.

Comment: ADL doesn't proceed if the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup contains a function declared at block scope. Is the global namespace not block scope? What exactly is block scope?

Comment: @NathanPierson Block scope would be anything within `{}` basically. So [this](https://godbolt.org/z/GvK66x) is unambiguous, since `fun` is declared in `main`.

Comment: @cigien Ahhh, thank you! So the declaration is in block scope and it'll look for a definition in global namespace scope? (Also, a minor note, the edit to show off block scope has invalidated the comment saying that it calls `First::fun`.)

Comment: @cigien Namespaces don't count as block scope though.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yeah. And true, I didn't see that the comment became wrong ;) Wrong comments are so much harder to catch than wrong code :(